# Golang strange format date

Tags: date, datetime, go, format

I have to convert a string date with this format:

```
Thu, 01 Nov 2018 14:20:34 +0700
```

.. into this format:

```
2018-11-01 14:20:34
```

I tried it with the following code:

```
dt_pub, err := time.Parse("RFC1123", Thu, 01 Nov 2018 14:20:34 +0700)
dt_pub.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
```

But unfortunately, the result looks like this:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Go [package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/).

`0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC` is the zero value for `time.Time`. The zero value is returned when a parsing error has occurred.

Check for errors. Use the `time.RFC1123Z` (RFC1123 with numeric zone) layout for parsing to match your input. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    dt_pub, err := time.Parse(time.RFC1123Z, "Thu, 01 Nov 2018 14:20:34 +0700")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(dt_pub)
    fmt.Println(dt_pub.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/rIoRVWArhfx

Output:

```
2018-11-01 14:20:34 +0700 +0700
2018-11-01 14:20:34
```